# bytes to friendly NSString format with MB or KB

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, double

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get file size properly and convert it to MB, GB in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846495/how-to-get-file-size-properly-and-convert-it-to-mb-gb-in-cocoa)

I have a `double` that is a number of bytes for each file. I want to create a string from this that is "friendly" and displays `KB` or `MB` as well as the converted number, e.g.:

- 1.2 MB
- 0.45 KB
- 169 KB

Is there a `NSString category` or method to do this?