# Get file size in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I tried several method to get file size, but always get zero.

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("movie", ofType: "mov")
let attr = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfFileSystemForPath(path!, error: nil)
if let attr = attr {
    let size: AnyObject? = attr[NSFileSize]
    println("File size = \(size)")
}
```

I get in log: `File size = nil`

Comment: Are you sure the file is in the app bundle at the top level?

Comment: Or try to use attributesOfItemAtPath instead of attributesOfFileSystemForPath. You can call .fileSize() on attr to get file size.

Comment: @tyt_g207 I believe that's the correct solution, but you should probably write it out as an answer instead of a comment so it's easier for future answer seekers to find.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Use `attributesOfItemAtPath` instead of `attributesOfFileSystemForPath`
+ call .fileSize() on your attr.

```
var filePath: NSString = "your path here"
var fileSize : UInt64
var attr:NSDictionary? = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(filePath, error: nil)
if let _attr = attr {
    fileSize = _attr.fileSize();
}
```

In Swift 2.0, we use do try catch pattern, like this:

```
let filePath = "your path here"
var fileSize : UInt64 = 0

do {
    let attr : NSDictionary? = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(filePath)

    if let _attr = attr {
        fileSize = _attr.fileSize();
    }
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

In Swift 3.x/4.0:

```
let filePath = "your path here"
var fileSize : UInt64

do {
    //return [FileAttributeKey : Any]
    let attr = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: filePath)
    fileSize = attr[FileAttributeKey.size] as! UInt64

    //if you convert to NSDictionary, you can get file size old way as well.
    let dict = attr as NSDictionary
    fileSize = dict.fileSize()
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: is it only me that thinks swift 2 just made things a *lot* worse. I was perfectly happy with &error. try-catch that are not expressions sucks.

Comment: You can always use `try?` and get an optional back.

Comment: what is this result? mine was f.e. `32768.0` is this Byte?? so fairly 32KB?

Comment: @BrandonA it's in byte

Answer (score 73):

Swift4: URL extension to easily access file attributes

Extension:

```
extension URL {
    var attributes: [FileAttributeKey : Any]? {
        do {
            return try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: path)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("FileAttribute error: \(error)")
        }
        return nil
    }

    var fileSize: UInt64 {
        return attributes?[.size] as? UInt64 ?? UInt64(0)
    }

    var fileSizeString: String {
        return ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: Int64(fileSize), countStyle: .file)
    }

    var creationDate: Date? {
        return attributes?[.creationDate] as? Date
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let fileUrl: URL
print("file size = \(fileUrl.fileSize), \(fileUrl.fileSizeString)")
```

Comment: `URL` provides the file attributes directly with `resourceValues(forKeys`.

Comment: This is the best answer. Should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 26):

In Swift 3+ you can get the file size directly from the URL, `(NS)FileManager` is not needed. And `ByteCountFormatter` is a smart way to display the file size.

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"movie", withExtension: "mov")!
do {
    let resourceValues = try url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.fileSizeKey])
    let fileSize = resourceValues.fileSize!
    print("File size = " + ByteCountFormatter().string(fromByteCount: Int64(fileSize)))
} catch { print(error) }
```

Actually you can get the file size from the `URL` even in Swift 2 but the syntax is a bit more cumbersome.

Comment: "Yes, but" Resource Value's `.fileSize` is defined as Int, whereas FileManager's `.size` comes as unsigned long long via NSNumber. Shouldn't make a difference on iOS anyhow in near future, but must be said.

Comment: I think using `Int` is totally fine as Apple's products are almost all 64 bits. A generic Int will able to fit all possible size value.

Comment: This works. About `FileManager.default.attributeOfItem`, I failed to get file attributes.

Answer (score 22):

**SWIFT 3** come from @Hoa's answer and plus a function let UInt64 to readable String.

```
func sizeForLocalFilePath(filePath:String) -> UInt64 {
    do {
        let fileAttributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: filePath)
        if let fileSize = fileAttributes[FileAttributeKey.size]  {
            return (fileSize as! NSNumber).uint64Value
        } else {
            print("Failed to get a size attribute from path: \(filePath)")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed to get file attributes for local path: \(filePath) with error: \(error)")
    }
    return 0
}
func covertToFileString(with size: UInt64) -> String {
    var convertedValue: Double = Double(size)
    var multiplyFactor = 0
    let tokens = ["bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB",  "EB",  "ZB", "YB"]
    while convertedValue > 1024 {
        convertedValue /= 1024
        multiplyFactor += 1
    }
    return String(format: "%4.2f %@", convertedValue, tokens[multiplyFactor])
}
```

Comment: Working well except a bug on covertToFileString. Replace `while size > 1024` by `while convertedValue > 1024` to avoid an infinit loop

Answer (score 18):

URL extension in Swift to get the file size, if any.

```
public extension URL {

    var fileSize: Int? {
        let value = try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.fileSizeKey])
        return value?.fileSize
    }
}
```

The reason for returning an optional Int is because an unknown file size cannot be considered as having a zero size.

Comment: Int has a limit ... only bytes upto 2GB will be stored in an Int variable

Answer (score 14):

Here is the answer from Biodave, with the correct file manager call

```
func sizeForLocalFilePath(filePath:String) -> UInt64 {
    do {
        let fileAttributes = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(filePath)
        if let fileSize = fileAttributes[NSFileSize]  {
            return (fileSize as! NSNumber).unsignedLongLongValue
        } else {
            print("Failed to get a size attribute from path: \(filePath)")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed to get file attributes for local path: \(filePath) with error: \(error)")
    }
    return 0
}
```

For Swift 4.2:

```
func sizeForLocalFilePath(filePath:String) -> UInt64 {
    do {
        let fileAttributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: filePath)
        if let fileSize = fileAttributes[FileAttributeKey.size]  {
            return (fileSize as! NSNumber).uint64Value
        } else {
            print("Failed to get a size attribute from path: \(filePath)")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed to get file attributes for local path: \(filePath) with error: \(error)")
    }
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Swift 4 solution:
This function return MB size.

```
func sizePerMB(url: URL?) -> Double {
    guard let filePath = url?.path else {
        return 0.0
    }
    do {
        let attribute = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: filePath)
        if let size = attribute[FileAttributeKey.size] as? NSNumber {
            return size.doubleValue / 1000000.0
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
    return 0.0
}
```

Comment: I was really tripping until I say this. Did almost the same things but didn't use the URL's path property. Thanks, mate!

Comment: how to make it return kb size ?

Answer (score 8):

Here is another two different implementation with **Swift 4**, one is formatted in details and other one is formatted by decimal.

The one with `NumberFomatter`:

```
func fileSize(fromPath path: String) -> String? {
    var size: Any?
    do {
        size = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: path)[FileAttributeKey.size]
    } catch (let error) {
        print("File size error: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
    guard let fileSize = size as? UInt64 else {
        return nil
    }

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
    return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: fileSize))
}
```

And the other one is defining with size units:

```
func fileSize(fromPath path: String) -> String? {
    guard let size = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: path)[FileAttributeKey.size],
        let fileSize = size as? UInt64 else {
        return nil
    }

    // bytes
    if fileSize < 1023 {
        return String(format: "%lu bytes", CUnsignedLong(fileSize))
    }
    // KB
    var floatSize = Float(fileSize / 1024)
    if floatSize < 1023 {
        return String(format: "%.1f KB", floatSize)
    }
    // MB
    floatSize = floatSize / 1024
    if floatSize < 1023 {
        return String(format: "%.1f MB", floatSize)
    }
    // GB
    floatSize = floatSize / 1024
    return String(format: "%.1f GB", floatSize)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try This.

```
let MyUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "*** Custom File Path ***")                  
let fileAttributes = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(MyUrl.path!)
let fileSizeNumber = fileAttributes[NSFileSize] as! NSNumber
let fileSize = fileSizeNumber.longLongValue
var sizeMB = Double(fileSize / 1024)
sizeMB = Double(sizeMB / 1024)
print(String(format: "%.2f", sizeMB) + " MB")
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3.0 try the following:

```
let fileSize = try! FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: "/bin/bash")[FileAttributeKey.size] as! Int
```

or even better:

```
let fileSize = (try! FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: "/bin/bash")[FileAttributeKey.size] as! NSNumber).uint64Value
```

Comment: How is the second one better? Why one should not use the NSNumber auto conversion? Also you should use try? and as? with if or guard statement as file operation can fail.

Answer (score 1):

Inspiration from a few other answers.

```
extension URL {
    var filesize: Int? {
        let set = Set.init([URLResourceKey.fileSizeKey])
        var filesize: Int?      
        do {
            let values = try self.resourceValues(forKeys: set)
            if let theFileSize = values.fileSize {
                filesize = theFileSize
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
        return filesize
    }

    var filesizeNicelyformatted: String? {
        guard let fileSize = self.filesize else {
            return nil
        }
        return ByteCountFormatter.init().string(fromByteCount: Int64(fileSize))
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a compact version written as happy method in Swift 2.0 for iOS9 via Xcode7:

```
func sizeForLocalFilePath(filePath:String) -> UInt64 {
    do {
        let fileAttributes = try NSFileManager().attributesOfFileSystemForPath(filePath)
        if let fileSize = fileAttributes[NSFileSystemSize] as? UInt64 {
            return fileSize
        } else {
            print("Failed to get a size attribute from path: \(filePath)")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed to get file attributes for local path: \(filePath) with error: \(error)")
    }
    return 0
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This doesn't work. It is checking the file system attributes, not the attribute of the file itself.

Answer (score -1):

```
final class URLManager {

   private init() {}
  
   class func convertToFileString(with size: UInt64) -> String {
        return ByteCountFormatter.init().string(fromByteCount: Int64(size))
    }

   class func sizeForLocalFilePath(filePath:String) -> UInt64 {
        do {
            let fileAttributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: filePath)
            if let fileSize = fileAttributes[FileAttributeKey.size]  {
                return (fileSize as! NSNumber).uint64Value
            } else {
                print("Failed to get a size attribute from path: \(filePath)")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed to get file attributes for local path: \(filePath) with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return 0
    }
    
    class func getFileSize(filePath:String)-> String {
        guard let url = URL(string: filePath) else {
            return convertToFileString(with: 0)
        }
        return getFileSize(filePath: url)
    }
    
    class func getFileSize(filePath : URL?)-> String {
        guard let url = filePath else {
            return convertToFileString(with: 0)
        }
        let value = sizeForLocalFilePath(filePath: url.path)
        return convertToFileString(with: value)
        
    }

}
```