# Extra Argument "error" in attributesOfFileSystemForPaths method in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

This is the declaration of a dictionary in Objective-C

```
 NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];
```

when I do it in swift 2.0 , error(mentioned as title of the question) is shown. can anyone help me in writing this in swift 2.0 ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: check this... and at least try or search before asking questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268145/get-file-size-in-swift