# Swift - Checking file sizes from a server before downloading is causing a lag in the app

Tags: swift, xcode, download, urlsession

I have a server that you can import videos to which when uploaded should downloads directly to the app. The issue is that the app will start downloading the video file before it has been fully uploaded to the server.

I set up a timer that runs every 10 seconds which checks the folder for new videos. If there is a new video, then I download it using a URL session. This is fine if the videos are already uploaded to the server before launching the app or if the video is very small and uploaded before the 10-second timer runs again but this isn't practical.

My idea was to check the video size and compare it a couple of seconds later. If the video sizes were the same, then download it. Below is the code I use to get the size and added to an array so I can compare it to a previous file size array.

```
 //videos data array is fetched from the server 

 for video in videos.components(separatedBy: "") {
       if !video.hasPrefix("._"){
           guard let videoUrl = video.encodeUrl() else {return}
           if let url = URL(string:String(self.session.imports_dir + "/" + videoUrl))  {

           //Gets the file size
           let data = NSData(contentsOf: url)
           let fileSize = Double(data!.length)

           videoArrayFileSize.append(fileSize)
  }
 }
}
```

If the videoArrayFileSize is different from the previous Filesize array, then do not download the video yet. The problem is that the above code is causing the app to lag severely even though I use

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async
```

Is there a better way to check the file size or another way to check if a file is completely uploaded on a server?

I can't edit the server code so I like a way to do it from the app if possible.

**UPDATE**

I tried the code below to get the size through the URLSession and it works with the test video [Big Bunny](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4) but not with the video on my server. I am guessing the HEAD content length is left empty in my videos giving 0.

```
func getFileSize(_ url: URL, completion: @escaping (Int64, Error?) -> Void){
    let timeoutInterval = 5.0
    var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: timeoutInterval)
    request.httpMethod = "HEAD"

    let group = DispatchGroup()
                 group.enter()


    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        let contentLength = response?.expectedContentLength ?? NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown
        completion(contentLength, error)
        group.leave()
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: The [documents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-init) are an interesting read

Comment: A better solution would be to have a API on the server which returns the file size of the file as a seperate call

Comment: *"I have a server that you can import videos to which when uploaded"* - so, my next thought is, when the file is actually uploaded (fully), have the server generate a silent notification alerting the App that a new file is available for download

Comment: The NSData(contentsOf: url) always drains the memory imo. If you don't mind you could use the AVAsset class to determine the height and width for your videos.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I asked the other developer if they could set up an API to return the file size but he said he couldn't because we copy and paste the file in the folder. I am not sure how true that is.

Comment: Is it a file server or a web server?

Comment: @MadProgrammer web server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to use a URL request and use the HTTP method "HEAD". Using the "expectedContentLength", you can find out the size of the file size and this causes no lag compared to the previous method mentioned.

```
func getFileSize(_ url: URL, completion: @escaping (Int64, Error?) -> Void){
    let timeoutInterval = 5.0
    var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: timeoutInterval)
    request.httpMethod = "HEAD"

    let group = DispatchGroup()
                 group.enter()

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        let contentLength = response?.expectedContentLength ?? NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown
        completion(contentLength, error)
        group.leave()
    }.resume()
}
```

you can convert the size to MB using the code below if required

```
let countBytes = ByteCountFormatter()
countBytes.allowedUnits = [.useMB]
countBytes.countStyle = .file
let fileSizeInMB = countBytes.string(fromByteCount: Int64(ENTERYOURVALUEHERE))
```

Comment: Hi, could you please give me a tip? I have to set a restriction to choose file over 32MB, when user wants to upload some file from iCloud Drive, for example. I can get size of selected file, through this extension https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268145/get-file-size-in-swift and get string value, "3MB". How can I compare size of selected file with max 32MB? I tried to cast Int(String) but it gives me nil.

Comment: I know it's kinda stupid solution https://imgur.com/DNwMCix I'll glad if you can help me somehow ...