# NSNumberFormatter from 13000 to 13K

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I would like to convert numbers to the shorter form using `NSNumberFormatter`.

For example: From 23000 to get 23K.

How I can do it using `NSNumberFormatter`?

I know it is possible to do calculation on my own, but in my case it is not right way to go.

Comment: Do you want that 23340 become 23k too, or not?

Comment: @Lolloz89 was about to ask the same. And 23850? Should it be 23k or 24k?

Comment: The point is that the "k" suffix is not recognized as a standard and international pattern. Anyway I think that if you want to use this pattern is because you don't want be so precise in representing a value, so I guess 23890 --> 23k. I'll write an answer to do this without using NSNumberFormatter.

Comment: a nice solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4716523/106435

Comment: possible duplicate of [ObjC/Cocoa class for converting size to human-readable string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572614/objc-cocoa-class-for-converting-size-to-human-readable-string)

Comment: The solution linked by @vikingosegundo is better than the solution that was accepted because it uses an NSFormatter subclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'K' suffix is not recognized as standard, so you can't do this using NSNumberFormatter.
anyway this is a simple way to do that.

```
-(NSString *)kFormatForNumber:(int)number{
    int result;
    if(number >= 1000){ 
        result = number/1000;

        NSString *kValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dk",result];
        return kValue;
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",number];
}
```