# Swift - how to count bytes and convert them to megabytes?

Tags: ios, swift

I try to add bytes with bytes in order to get space that will be occupied by photos which i retrieve from internet.

I have following code, it gets sizes in bytes for each id in `array` of `id`

```
    var diskSpace:Int64 = 0

    for var i = 0; i < array.count; i++  {

        let id = array[i]

        let urlString = "urlToFetchData"

        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: []) {
                let json = JSON(data: data)

                let size = Int64(json["size"].stringValue)

                diskSpace = diskSpace + size!

            }
        }

    }

   var diskSpaceInMb = diskSpace / 1024 / 1024
   print("diskSpaceInMb is \(diskSpaceInMb)")
```

for example, I try to get size of three elements, which have following size in bytes (these sizes in bytes I receive in json)

```
3223653
5855382
8948976
```

when the code above is executed i receive result of

```
diskSpaceInMb is 8
```

which is obviously not try

How to convert bytes to megabytes correctly ?

Comment: Could you use [NSByteCountFormatter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12674661/300836) for your purposes?

Comment: You should print `diskSpace` too to verify your loop is working as expected.

Comment: @Alexey K you should fetch your data asynchronously

Answer (score 60):

```
let fileSizeWithUnit = ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: diskSpace, countStyle: .file)
print("File Size: \(fileSizeWithUnit)")
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is obviously in the for loop. Maybe the JSON is not as you expect.

Another reason why this might fail is the you use the `try?` keyword, which in this context it means that it gives you a value if it succeeds, but otherwise it returns `nil`. In your case, it may silently fail. If you want to check if it fails, you could add an `else` branch.

[image: playground example]

Comment: It's the same code as above... It just has some dubugging info on the right.

Comment: how do i copypaste your screenshot